# best practices on floating point precision in python

Tags: python, floating-point, double, precision

Earlier tonight, a friend of mine just handed me this cute problem. The problem says:

> Make a program in **MATLAB** to check whether a point is inside a triangle or not. Not to forget to check if the point is on the border as well.
>   Triangle points are `x=(0,0)`,`y=(0,1)`and`z=(1,0)`

The problem is not hard to solve. The idea is to find the equation of the hypotenuse and check if the point lies on any leg of the triangle. Check for inside and outside turns out not to be that difficult, however.

I made the code on **MATLAB**, the logic seems to be fine. But the problem is that the result are not in a harmony with that logic! I started questioning my code since I am not such skillful in MATLAB. Nevertheless, I gave it a try on my preferred language, Python.

Here is my code:

```py
def isInsideTriangle(x,y):
    if  x == 0 or y == 0 or y ==  1-x:
        print('on the border of the triangle')
    elif x > 1 or y > 1 or x < 0 or y < 0 or y > 1-x:
            print('outside of the triangle')
            print(1-x)  # check the value
    else:
        # verbose these values to double check
        print(1-x)
        print(y)
        print(type(y))
        print(type(1-x))
        print(y==(1-x))
        print('inside of the triangle')

isInsideTriangle(0.2,0.8)
```

When trying with this two values, the result on console shall be `on the border`. However, the program said it is `inside`! I tried to switch between `x` and `y` i.e. `isInsideTriangle(0.8,0.2)` but the program outputted the expected result this time.

This leaded me to realize that there is no thing to do with the logic but with **floating-point precision**. I increased the size of the variables on MATLAB to be *64 bit* precision and the program works fine.

**My question now**

> As a Python guy, what are the best programming practices to avoid such problems in Python? How can we avoid such annoying problems specially in production environments?

Comment: Have you tried using `Decimal` instead of floats? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try to give it a try. However, do you thing it is the best practice just to choose Decimal on every numerical variable?

Comment: `Decimal` is still floating-point and still subject to almost every limitation of binary floating point. It's just *decimal* floating point, so its behavior lines up better with the intuition of humans trained to think of decimal as the natural representation of numbers. It still can't represent numbers like 1/3, and it still has rounding error.

Comment: If you want to check if a point is inside a polygon, I suggest using the winding number: http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Forewords

Your question is a specialization of "*Is a point inside a regular polygon?*" by regular I mean not self intersecting or multi polygons as we can often found in GIS system. And by extension because your are asking for triangle, I'll assume the polygon is convex.

[image]

What is interesting, is that cross product is the key to solve it. When you are dealing with vectors in 2D plane, cross products are orthogonal to this plane. The useful information to extract is: does it point upward or downward?

[image]

Float Arithmetic errors will happen, and it becomes critical when the cross product is close to zero, but not equal to, then it will have a sign instead of being null.

To check if your point is inside the polygon, it merely boils down to check if all cross products between edge and the point have the same signs, eg.: `sign(h x w) = -1`.

In the same way, to check if the polygon is convex is about to check that all cross products of consecutive edges have the same signs, eg.: `sign(u x v) = -1`.

### Implementation

Let's build a small class to check if a point is inside (on the edge or outside) of a regular convex polygon:

```
import numpy as np
class cpoly:

    def __init__(self, points=[[0,0], [0,1], [1,0]], assert_convexity=True):
        """
        Initialize 2D Polygon with a sequence of 2D points
        """
        self._points = np.array(points)
        assert self.p.shape[0] >= 3
        assert self.p.shape[1] == 2
        assert self.is_convex or not(assert_convexity)

    @property
    def n(self):
        return self.p.shape[0]

    @property
    def p(self):
        return self._points

    @property
    def is_convex(self):
        """
        Check convexity of the polygon (operational for a non intersecting polygon)
        """
        return self.contains()

    def contains(self, p=None, debug=False, atol=2e-16):
        """
        Check if a 2D convex polygon contains a point (also used to assess convexity)
        Returns:
           -1: Point is oustide the polygon
            0: Point is close to polygon edge (epsilon ball)
           +1: Point is inside the polygon
        """
        s = None
        c = False
        n = self.n
        for k in range(n):
            # Vector Differences:
            d1 = self.p[(k+1)%n,:] - self.p[k%n,:]
            if p:
                d2 = p - self.p[k%n,:]
            else:
                d2 = self.p[(k+2)%n,:] - self.p[(k+1)%n,:]
            # Cross Product:
            z = np.cross(d1, d2)
            if np.allclose(z, 0, atol=atol):
                s_ = 0
                c = True
            else:
                s_ = np.sign(z)
            # Debug Helper:
            if debug:
                print("k = %d, d1 = %s, d2 = %s, z = %.32f, s = %d" % (k, d1, d2, z, s_))
            # Check if cross product sign change (excluded null, when point is colinear with the segment)
            if s and (s_ != s) and not(s_ == 0):
                # Nota: Integer are exact if float representable, therefore comparizons are correct
                return -1
            s = s_
        if c:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    def plot(self, axe=None):
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
        if not(axe):
            fig, axe = plt.subplots()
            axe.plot(self.p[:,0], self.p[:,1], 'x', markersize=10, label='Points $p_i$')
            axe.add_patch(Polygon(self.p, alpha=0.4, label='Area'))
            axe.set_xlabel("$x$")
            axe.set_ylabel("$y$")
            axe.set_title("Polygon")
            axe.set_aspect('equal')
            axe.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper left')
            axe.grid()
        return axe.get_figure(), axe
```

The class is initialized with a list of 2D points (by default it is yours).

```
p = cpoly()
```

On my setup, float precision is about:

```
e = np.finfo(np.double).eps # 2.220446049250313e-16
```

We create a trial dataset for testing purposes:

```
p = cpoly()
r = [
    [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], # Polygon vertices
    [0,0.5], [-e,0.6], [e,0.4], [0.1, 0.1], [1,1],
    [0.5+e,0.5], [0.3-e,0.7], [0.7+e/10,0.3],
    [0, 1.2], [1.2, 0.], # Those points make your logic fails
    [0.2,0.8], [0.1,0.9],
    [0.8+10*e,0.2], [0.9+10*e,0.1]
]
```

If we adapt your function to have compliant output:

```
def isInsideTriangle(x,y):
    if  x == 0 or y == 0 or y ==  1-x:
        return 0
    elif x > 1 or y > 1 or x < 0 or y < 0 or y > 1-x:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

Then we check trial points to see if both our functions behave well:

```
_, axe = p.plot()
cols = {-1: 'red', 0:'orange', 1:'green'}
for x in r:
    q1 = p.contains(x)
    q2 = isInsideTriangle(*x)
    print(q1==q2)
    axe.plot(*x, 'o', markersize=4, color=cols[q1])
```

[image]

With this setup, all points are correctly classified. But you can see that your algorithm is flawed. Mainly the following line:

```
if  x == 0 or y == 0 or y ==  1-x:
```

Fails to reject `[0, 1.2]` and `[1.2, 0.]`.

#### Points close to an edge and Float Arithmetic Error

Even for point exactly on the edge like `[0.2,0.8]` floating point error leads to point misclassification. The following point would make the cross product not exactly equal to zero as it should. See details bellow:

```
p.contains([0.2,0.8], debug=True) # True
# k = 0, d1 = [0 1], d2 = [0.2 0.8], z = -0.20000000000000001110223024625157, s = -1
# k = 1, d1 = [ 1 -1], d2 = [ 0.2 -0.2], z = 0.00000000000000005551115123125783, s = 0
# k = 2, d1 = [-1  0], d2 = [-0.8  0.8], z = -0.80000000000000004440892098500626, s = -1
```

This is why we must add a ball of radius `atol` to check if is actually zero for the given tolerance:

```
if np.allclose(z, 0, atol=atol):
    s_ = 0
    # ...
else:
    s_ = np.sign(z)
```

It means we must accept that points close enough to the edge (from both side) are considered to be contained into the polygon. This is inherent from Float Arithmetic, the best you can do is to tune `atol` to an acceptable value for your application. Or you can find out another logic or data model which does not suffer this problem.

#### Zooming to precision scale

If we zoom to precision scale to see what happens close to the edge, we got:

```
n = 40
lim = np.array([0.5,0.5]) + [-n*e/2, +n*e/2]
x = np.linspace(lim[0], lim[1], 30)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
x, y = X.reshape(-1), Y.reshape(-1)

_, axe = p.plot()
axe.set_xlim(lim)
axe.set_ylim(lim)
for r in zip(x,y):
    q = p.contains(r)
    axe.plot(*r, 'o', color=cols[q], markersize=2)
```

[image]

We see that some points very close to the edge, but inside or outside of the polygon, are classified as "on the edge". This is because of the epsilon ball criterion. You can also observe that points are not equally spaced (no matter if I used `linspace`) because of it is impossible to express `10` as an integral power of `2`.

#### Conclusion

The solution above is a generalization of your problem, performing in `O(n)`. It might seems to be overkill but it is **general** (it works for any regular polygon) and **comprehensive** (it relies on a well known geometric concept).

Actually, the algorithm simply check if the point stays at the same side of all edges of the polygon when walking through the path. If it does, then it concludes the point is inside the polygon, that is!

The above solution is off course affected by float arithmetic error because it relies on float computation (see point `10`). Fortunately, using epsilon ball test, we can mitigate it.

#### Reference

If you want to deeper understand finite precision arithmetic, I would advise you to read the excellent book: [Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, J. Higham](https://books.google.be/books?hl=en&lr=&id=7J52J4GrsJkC&oi=fnd&pg=PR3&dq=numerical%20stability%20and%20accuracy&ots=B5k2xlyt23&sig=PFTe9ju_2hTpB3_cw937_EU0z80#v=onepage&q=numerical%20stability%20and%20accuracy&f=false).

#### Bonus

Bellow a comparison of all answers with the trial dataset:

[image]

We can give some context on the different kind of "errors" underlined by this soft check:

- Points `11` and `12` are misclassified by `@MagedSaeed` because of the design flaw;
- `@MahmoudElshahat` use straight float equality in its logic, this is why it returns different results for equivalent class of points (eg.: points `0` to `2`, polygon points);
- `@SamMason` uses the simplest logic with an epsilon ball test. It seems to have a biggest error rate because it does not discriminate between inside and on the border (we can ignore all points where exact answer is `0` and its function returned `1`). IMO, this it is the best `if-then` algorithm presented which runs in `O(1)`. Additionally it can easily be updated to take into account the 3 states logic;
- Point `10` was deliberately designed to challenge logic at the border, the point is clearly outside the polygon from distance with a magnitude about the machine precision. This is where float arithmetic error becomes significant and the logic is more fuzzy: *how far from the edge is acceptable and tractable?*

Comment: Thanks of this detailed answer. Really love it. However, I have two questions: is my algorithm correct? second, how about the best practices regarding floating point precision? you did not mention any. I would like your comments on this. Thanks

Comment: @MagedSaeed I have updated my post to answer your questions. Your algorithm is not correct (see details above). I have added content about Float Arithmetic Error and a reference. Let me know if I have sufficiently addressed your questions. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really added big value.

Comment: @MagedSaeed You are welcome, I had fun to answer your question.

Comment: according to your comparison, I did not so bad comparing to other ideas. This is good news btw. ::)))

Answer (score 5):

First of all, your logic is incorrect. Consider the case of `x=0.9`, `y=0.9`. This is clearly outside the triangle, but does not satisfy any of the conditions `x > 1 or y > 1 or x < 0 or y < 0`.

Second of all, any floating-point arithmetic which involves an equality comparison -- like testing if a point is "on the border" of a shape -- is likely to be affected by precision problems. Reworking your logic to instead test whether a point is *within a small margin* of the border is likely to work better.

I would recommend against the use of the `Decimal` class for anything that isn't *natively* a decimal number, like currency. Performing anything other than basic arithmetic on a Decimal (such as `math.sqrt`) will internally convert it to a float anyway.

Comment: Oh thanks @duskwuff for your note on the logic. I just updated accordingly. I thing I missed this condition `or y > 1-x` is there anything else?

Comment: Again, thanks for your note on the border. However, adding accuracy margin may not make things better. Consider giving this number as a test case, most probably the result will be erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

your code seems to be checking conditions unnecessarily, I'd implement it as somewhat closer to:

```
def isInsideTriangle(x, y):
    return (
        x >= 0 and x <= 1 and
        y >= 0 and y <= 1 - x
    )
```

this feels closer to how I'd think about it as a person: first make sure the `x` axis is in bounds, then check the `y` axis.

you can then put some tests into the code:

```
tests = [
    (0, 0, True),
    (0, 1, True),
    (1, 0, True),
    (1, 1, False),
    (-1, 1, False),
    (2, 1, False),
    (1, 1, False),
    (0.5, 0.5, True),
    (0.1, 0.9, True),
    (0.2, 0.9, False),
    (0.9, 0.9, False),
]

for x, y, expected in tests:
    result = isInsideTriangle(x,y)
    if result != expected:
        print(f"failed with ({x},{y}) = {result}")
```

to make sure it behaves, note that there are nice frameworks around for automatically running tests like this on your code

as pointed out by @duskwuff, floating point numbers are only approximate (to around ~15 decimal digits, Python uses double precision/64bit floating point numbers) but rounding errors can easily cause things to end up on the "wrong side" of a comparison.  it's also why math libraries include "redundant" operations like `log1p` which calculates `log(1 + x)` correctly when `x` is "near zero", e.g, try:

```
from math import log, log1p

print(log(1.0 + 1e-20))
print(log1p(1e-20))
```

these should be the "same", but due to rounding the naive version suffers from a "catastrophic loss of precision" and hence prints `0.0`

one way to deal with this is to allow for some amount of expected error (commonly called epsilon), for example the above function could be rewritten as:

```
def isInsideTriangleEps(x, y, epsilon=1e-10):
    assert epsilon >= 0
    return (
        x >= -epsilon and x - 1 <= epsilon and
        y >= -epsilon and x - 1 + y <= epsilon
    )
```

which allows some user specified tolerance

Comment: Thanks for you comments on the floating point precision. Really helpful! However, I can see that your solution to the problem checks only if the point is inside triangle or outside. What about on the borders? The problem requires to check whether a given point is on the border, inside or outside of the triangle.

Comment: to me the wording of the question was to make sure you used `>=` and `<=` operators rather than just `>` and `<`.  they/you also haven't defined any border width, so it doesn't really make sense to say if a point is on an infinitesimally wide line, floating point (im)precision also means that this will almost certainly do the wrong thing in obscure cases

Answer (score 1):

Answering your questions:

> is my algorithm correct? second, how about the best practices regarding floating point precision?

- no your logic is not correct. **Edited**: see comments
- second, To make it work we should avoid the lossy operations, where 1-0.8 will be rounded up for example to '0.19999999999999996' and lose a fraction of its real value,

so we should replace the condition "x == 1-y" to "x + y == 1" and change "y > 1-x" to "x + y > 1"

**Edit**: Remove x==1 or y==1  also redundant x>1 or y>1

then it will work:

```
def isInsideTriangle(x,y):
    if  x+y==1:
        print('on the border of the triangle')
    elif x < 0 or y < 0 or x+y>1:
            print('outside of the triangle')
            print(1-x)  # check the value
    else:
        # verbose these values to double check
        print(1-x)
        print(y)
        print(type(y))
        print(type(1-x))
        print(y==(1-x))
        print('inside of the triangle')

isInsideTriangle(0.8,0.2)
isInsideTriangle(0.2,0.8)
```

output:

```
on the border of the triangle
on the border of the triangle
```

Comment: Comparing float with equality is not a good option, you should instead use epsilon ball criterion. The OP logic and yours fails to reject points such as (0,10) which is obviously outside the polygon.

Comment: You are right, i modified the logic in my answer and put only x+y==1 to check points on the boundary